# How to vertically align divs or spans, and float them in opposite directions?

Tags: html, css

Look at the example:

```
<td>
  <div id='a'></div>
  <div id='b'></div>
</td>
```

I want div#a to be floated to left, div#b floated to right, and both of them to be vertically aligned. How to do that?

Example: https://usosweb.mimuw.edu.pl/kontroler.php?_action=actionx:katalog2/index()
Use one of the input texts, and look at the footnote of autocompleter. I want to get similar effect but both "column" to be vertically aligned to MIDDLE (apologise for lack of that).

Comment: I need it for some sort of autocompleter I write in js.

Comment: How does that relate to your requirements?!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for: I made a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/RK2ak/

```
<div class="wrap">
<p id="a"> test</p>
<p id="b"> test</p>
</div>

#a{
    float:left;
}
#b{
    float:right;
}
.wrap{
    width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to answer when you dont say anything about what you are actually trying to do.
The following does no good, but it answers your question:

```
<div>
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
</div>

<style>
  div { width: 100px }
  #a{ background: red; float:left }
  #b{ background: blue; float:right }
</style>
```

**EDIT**

Based on your update, what you need is line-height:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">
    <p>lorem ipsum whatever</p>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  #container { width: 500px }
  #a,#b{ display: block; float:left; width: 240px; background: red; line-height: 35px;   height:35px }
  p{ line-height: 1em; display: inline-block; }
</style>
```

[This updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHYWR/1/) illustrates the concept. Basically, the containers need a `height` and a `line-height`, so that `height` = `line-height`.

Comment: I've particullarized my question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want both divs to be vertically centered, with one on the left and one on the right. Vertical alignment has always been tricky with CSS, and while there are now a few simple and elegant solutions, they were only introduced recently and thus are not yet very compatible. The traditional alternative is to use tables, but we can avoid that if you know how tall your `<div>`s are going to be.

Here's an example layout that assumes `#left` and `#right` are always 100px tall, and aligns them relative to the document body. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NbLnW/))

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id='pad'></div>
  <div id='left'>left</div>
  <div id='right'>right</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
*      {margin:0; padding:0;}
body   {position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%;}
#pad   {height:50%; min-height:50px; margin-bottom:-50px;}
#left  {float:left;  width:100px; height:100px; background:#f88;}
#right {float:right; width:100px; height:100px; background:#88f;}
```